# Woocommerce Exclude Category from products Front end and Admin Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Day, I found this script from businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-exclude-category-from-products-shortcode/ how to use this script to exclude uncategorized from the front and admin panel

what I'm trying to do is if the product has 1 or more categories exclude uncategorized from the product

```
function bbloomer_exclude_cat_shortcodes($query_args){
 
    $query_args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array('uncategorized'), // Don't display products from this category
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )); 
 
    return $query_args;
}
```

**AMMENDED**

see an example what I'm looking for
[image]

The Client is very old school and he does not want to go to product and remove uncategorized then save and then go back to product and select the correct category

Comment: The code you have shown appears to be for a shortcode to list multiple products, but what you are asking, rather appears to be about how a single product displays(?). For the latter, you’ll probably have to check where/how the list of categories to output is determined within the single product templates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be done via the Wordpress back-end options?

Visit WooCommerce > Products > Categories > Select Default Category you wish to use > Delete Uncategorized

This should remove the uncategorized without changing any code

Comment: thanks for your answer, I can do that but the problem is the client has over 10k Products and 2k of that products has no categories yet. I can remove the uncategorized as you said but then the 2k will move to the default category. I was looking for something in the line of if (is_admin()) {
   $query_args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array('uncategorized'), // Don't display products from this category
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )); 
 
    return $query_args;
}

Comment: You could add a filter to the wordpress website that will remove the category although with them not having another / default category it may still categorize them by default but on the front it end it should remove the uncategorized tag.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet worked for me:

> this code works for yitheme bulk product edit, it has been tested with the developers of the plugin.

***Edited***

**To Explain wat the code snippet below does you will need to install yitheme bulk edit plugin https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-bulk-product-editing/
this plugin allows you to bulk edit products. I needed to remove a category from the category list if more than 1 category is available
the following line if ( $c->term_id != 1930 ) { you need to replace 1930 with the id of the category that you would like to remove from the list.
For example, if you have 3 categories for one product and category B, id is 1930 the that will e removed from the product.
,
but when a product only has category B, it will stay as a category**

```
if( !function_exists('yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_disable_uncategorized_on_column_tab') ) {
 function yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_disable_uncategorized_on_column_tab( $value, $column_name, $post ) {

 if ( 'categories' == $column_name ) {
 $cats       = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
 $cats       = ! empty( $cats ) ? $cats : array();
 $cats_count = count( $cats );
 $cats_html  = '';
 $loop       = 0;
 $my_cats_id = array();

 if ( $cats_count == 1 ) {
 $cats_html .= $cats[0]->name;
 } else {
 foreach ( $cats as $c ) {
 $loop ++;
 if ( $c->term_id != 1930 ) {

 $cats_html .= $c->name;
 if ( $loop < $cats_count ) {
 $cats_html .= ', ';
 }
 $my_cats_id[] = $c->term_id;
 }
            }
         }

 $value = '<div class="yith-wcbep-select-values">' . esc_html( $cats_html ) . '</div> <input class="yith-wcbep-select-selected" type="hidden" value="' . wp_json_encode( $my_cats_id ) . '">';
 }

 return $value;
 }

   add_filter( 'yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns', 'yith_wcbep_manage_custom_columns_disable_uncategorized_on_column_tab', 10, 3 );
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -3):

Correct me If I am wrong you want to remove categorized category from your product_category filter. Now you have n number of products which dont have any category?

Uncategory itself is category by, and no product is assigned by default to it. In Case If you want to hide it use filter use below code , checked and running

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'organicweb_exclude_category', 10, 3 );
function organicweb_exclude_category( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) 
{
  $new_terms = array();

  if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_page() )
 {
    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) 
{
      if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'uncategorised/*It can be any category name*/' ) ) )
 {
        $new_terms[] = $term;
}
}
 $terms = $new_terms;
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Please do not misuse comments to advertise your unrelated other posts.

Comment: @Avik Banerjee, it's almost there. but not yet I want uncategorized Category not to display if the product has more than 1 category allocated to it?

Comment: please see amended section on my question